# How to save each input values?

Tags: jquery

I have a demo here of my problem : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOzQaj

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.del').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(450);
        if ($('.read_content').is(':visible')) {
            $('.read_content').fadeOut(1000);
        };
    });

    $('.read').on('click', function(){
        $('.read_content').toggle();        
        $('.name').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.user_name').html());
        $('.email').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.user_email').html());
        $('.phone').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.user_phone').html());     
    });

    $('.edit').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').toggleClass('ready');

        if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').hasClass('ready')) {         
            $(this).html('Save');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').html('').append('<input class="vals" type="text">');     
        }
        else{           
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').html($('.vals').val());
            $(this).html('Edit').removeClass('ready');
        }       
    });
});
```

what i`m trying to do is when i click on the edit(text changes to save) button, each TD element text will be changed to input so it can be edited each field (Name, Email, Phone), and when i click again on save, the fields are changed but only with the text of the first field, so how can i make it to save the different data in each field?

for example now if you type for
Name: v
Email: v@v.com
phone: 32323

and when you click save all fields will change to v, instead of the different data for all email and phone fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your else part in `edit` click handler should be like this:

```
 ....
 $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).find(".vals").val());
 });
 ....
```

So your `edit` handler will look like this:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').toggleClass('ready');

    if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').hasClass('ready')) {         
        $(this).html('Save');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').html('').append('<input class="vals" type="text">');     
    }
    else{       
        // OBSERVE THE CHANGE HERE  
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').each(function(){
           $(this).html($(this).find(".vals").val()); //$(this) refers to the each td
        });
        $(this).html('Edit').removeClass('ready');
    }       
});
```

See the entire working code below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.del').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(450);
  if ($('.read_content').is(':visible')) {
   $('.read_content').fadeOut(1000);
  };
 });

 $('.read').on('click', function(){
  $('.read_content').toggle();  
  $('.name').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.user_name').html());
  $('.email').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.user_email').html());
  $('.phone').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.user_phone').html());  
 });

 $('.edit').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').toggleClass('ready');
  
  if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').hasClass('ready')) {   
   $(this).html('Save');
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').html('').append('<input class="vals" type="text">');  
  }
  else{  
            // OBSERVE THE CHANGE HERE 
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').each(function(){
               $(this).html($(this).find(".vals").val());
            });
   $(this).html('Edit').removeClass('ready');
  }  
 });
});
```

```css
.read_content{
 margin: 105px 0 0 25px;
 width: 350px; 
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: none;
}

.edit{
 background-color: green;
 color: #fff;
}

.del{
 background-color: red;
 color: #fff;
}

.green{
 background-color: green;
}

.ready{ 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab" border=1 cellpadding=5px>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th> 
    <th colspan="3">Actions</th>   
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="user_name">John Shepard</td>
    <td class="user_email">Shepard@gmail.com</td>
    <td class="user_phone">202105</td>
    <td>
     <button class="read">Read</button>
     <button class="edit">Edit</button>
     <button class="del">Delete</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="user_name">Aria T`Loak</td>
    <td class="user_email">aria@gmail.com</td>
    <td class="user_phone">303102</td>
    <td>
     <button class="read">Read</button>
     <button class="edit">Edit</button>
     <button class="del">Delete</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="user_name">Liara T`Soni</td>
    <td class="user_email">liara@gmail.com</td>
    <td class="user_phone">405098</td>
    <td>
     <button class="read">Read</button>
     <button class="edit">Edit</button>
     <button class="del">Delete</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <div class="read_content">
  <label>Name:</label><span class="name"></span><br>
  <label>Email:</label><span class="email"></span><br>
  <label>Phone:</label><span class="phone"></span>
 </div>
```

Also a pen, incase you need it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKqQJw

Comment: well done i was about to suggest to OP to use id attribute for each field and retrieve it individually

Comment: The "Edit" button does not maintain the previous value

Comment: @Aroniaina: I dont think so it does in the original Pen provided by the OP either

Answer (score 2):

i think this will help . you have go throw  the total collection by using the a .each loop

code is

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').toggleClass('ready');

        if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').hasClass('ready')) {         
            $(this).html('Save');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').html('').append('<input class="vals" type="text">');     
        }
        else{           
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').each(function(i,v){
                            $(this).html($('.vals').val());
                        }) ;
            $(this).html('Edit').removeClass('ready');
        }       
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this, and improve CSS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".input-form").prop('disabled',true);
  $('.del').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(450);
    if ($('.read_content').is(':visible')) {
      $('.read_content').fadeOut(1000);
    };
  });

  $('.read').on('click', function(){
    $('.read_content').toggle();  
    $('.name').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.name-input').val());
    $('.email').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.mail-input').val());
    $('.phone').html($(this).closest('tr').find('.phone-input').val());  
  });

  $('.edit').on('click', function(){
    var toDo = $(this).html();
    if(toDo == "Edit"){
      $(this).html("Save");
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.input-form').prop('disabled',false);
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.input-form').addClass("active");
    }
    else if((toDo == "Save")){
      $(this).html("Edit");
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.input-form').prop('disabled',true);
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.input-form').removeClass("active");                       
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
.read_content{
        margin: 105px 0 0 25px;
        width: 350px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: none;
}

.edit{
        background-color: green;
        color: #fff;
}

.del{
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff;
}

.green{
        background-color: green;
}

.ready{ 
}

.input-form{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #006dcc;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
}
.input-form.active{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #006dcc;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="tab" border=1 cellpadding=5px>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th> 
      <th colspan="3">Actions</th>   
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="user_name">
        <input type="text" class="input-form name-input" value="John Shepard"/>
      </td>
      <td class="user_email">
        <input type="mail" class="input-form mail-input" value="Shepard@gmail.com"/>
      </td>
      <td class="user_phone">                                
        <input type="text" class="input-form phone-input" value="202105"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="read">Read</button>
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="del">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="user_name">
        <input type="text" class="input-form name-input" value="Aria T`Loak"/>
      </td>
      <td class="user_email">
        <input type="mail" class="input-form mail-input" value="aria@gmail.com"/>
      </td>
      <td class="user_phone">                                
        <input type="text" class="input-form phone-input" value="202105"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="read">Read</button>
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="del">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="user_name">
        <input type="text" class="input-form name-input" value="Liara T`Soni"/>
      </td>
      <td class="user_email">
        <input type="mail" class="input-form mail-input" value="liara@gmail.com"/>
      </td>
      <td class="user_phone">                                
        <input type="text" class="input-form phone-input" value="405098"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="read">Read</button>
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="del">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="read_content">
  <label>Name:</label><span class="name"></span><br>
  <label>Email:</label><span class="email"></span><br>
  <label>Phone:</label><span class="phone"></span>
</div>
```